# solving two nonlinear equations with nleqslv packain R

Tags: r

I am using nleqslv package to solve two non linear equations where the two unknowns are positive .each time the termination code is (3) which means that no better solution found and the results are too far from the actual values

```
library(nleqslv) ## solving nonlinear equations
R.bar=0.4361885
R2.bar=0.2137403
initial=c(0.4361885,1.659362)
sq.initial=sqrt(initial)
fun <- function(z){
 f=numeric(2)
  x=z^2
  f[1]=(exp(-(x[1]^2)/(2*(x[2]))))*((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^3)*0.375)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^5)*0.078125)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^7)*0.01139)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^9)*0.0012817)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^11)*0.000117))-(4*R.bar/sqrt(2*pi))
  f[2]=(exp(-(x[1]^2)/(2*(x[2]))))*((((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^2)*0.25)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^4)*0.0834)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^6)*-0.04286)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^8)*-0.05798)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^10)*-0.03594)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^12)*-0.01948)+
                                          (((x[1]/sqrt(x[2]))^14)*-0.005274))-(R2.bar)
   f
   }
testnslv(sq.initial,fun)
```

Comment: With "... too far from the actual values" do you mean that you know the solution? Do you know that there is a solution?

Comment: yes, I am doing a simulation from certain distribution and these are the estimates. so I know the actual parameters and need to evaluate my method of estimation.